# Load function in loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have an working `load`function. But when I use this in an loop it won't work, the data is not pulled or the code is not (correctly) triggered. When viewing the console there is no error. So hard to determine why the data is not shown.

In this code when the users selects an item of the first `select` list the second `select` list is updated with the corresponding data.

```
<select class="form-control" id="add_off_relatie_id" name="add_off_relatie_id" onchange="add_contact_table_4()">';
    foreach ($rows_adr as $row_adr)
    {
        echo '<option ';if($row['relatie_id'] == $row_adr['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_adr['id'].'">'.$row_adr['naam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="add_off_contact_id" name="add_off_contact_id" onchange="validate_add_off_table_4()">';
    foreach ($rows_cnt as $row_cnt) if($row_cnt['relatie_id'] == $row['relatie_id'])
    {
        echo '<option ';if($row['contact_id'] == $row_cnt['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_cnt['id'].'">'.$row_cnt['naam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add_contact_table_4()
{
    $('#add_off_contact_id').load('includes/dynamic_drop/relatie_contact.php?choice=' + document.getElementById('add_off_relatie_id').value)
}
</script>
```

But when using the same structure in an for loop and the user select an new item in the first `select` list the data in the second `select` list is not updated.

```
<select class="form-control" id="edit_off_relatie_id['.$i.']" name="edit_off_relatie_id" onchange="edit_contact_table_4(this, '.$i.')">';
    foreach ($rows_adr as $row_adr)
    {
        echo '<option ';if($row_table_4['relatie_id'] == $row_adr['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_adr['id'].'">'.$row_adr['naam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="edit_off_contact_id['.$i.']" name="edit_off_contact_id" onchange="validate_edit_off_table_4(this, '.$i.')">';
    foreach ($rows_cnt as $row_cnt) if($row_cnt['relatie_id'] == $row_table_4['relatie_id'])
    {
        echo '<option ';if($row_table_4['contact_id'] == $row_cnt['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_cnt['id'].'">'.$row_cnt['naam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function edit_contact_table_4(selectVeld, nr)
{
    $('edit_off_contact_id['+nr+']').load('includes/dynamic_drop/relatie_contact.php?choice=' + document.getElementById('edit_off_relatie_id['+nr+']').value)
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: @HarishST The ID's are unique by `$i`

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried te remove `['$i']` from the code and it works on the first  of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are used to special tasks, like getting attributes, like in `input[name=something]`, so they need to be escaped:

```
$('edit_off_contact_id\\['+nr+'\\]').load('includes/dynamic_drop/relatie_contact.php?choice=' + document.getElementById('edit_off_relatie_id\\['+nr+'\\]').value)
```

Or you can change string format for your ids:

```
<select class="form-control" id="edit_off_relatie_id-' . $i . '" name="edit_off_relatie_id" onchange="edit_contact_table_4(this, ' . $i . ')">';
    foreach ($rows_adr as $row_adr)
    {
        echo '<option ';if($row_table_4['relatie_id'] == $row_adr['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_adr['id'].'">'.$row_adr['naam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="edit_off_contact_id-' . $i . '" name="edit_off_contact_id" onchange="validate_edit_off_table_4(this, ' . $i . ')">';
    foreach ($rows_cnt as $row_cnt) if($row_cnt['relatie_id'] == $row_table_4['relatie_id'])
    {
        echo '<option ';if($row_table_4['contact_id'] == $row_cnt['id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} echo 'value="'.$row_cnt['id'].'">'.$row_cnt['naam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">
function edit_contact_table_4(selectVeld, nr)
{
    $(`edit_off_contact_id-${nr}`).load('includes/dynamic_drop/relatie_contact.php?choice=' + document.getElementById(`edit_off_relatie_id-${nr}`).value)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thx, this helped me an lot. I had to use `$('edit_off_contact_id\\['+nr+'\\]').load('includes/dynamic_drop/relatie_contact.php?choice=' + document.getElementById('edit_off_relatie_id['+nr+']').value)`